# BASH output result of query to another bash script, then execute second script

Tags: bash, postgresql, shell

I'm completely new to bash script writing. I have a query that generates an output. I need to add that output to another bash script, then run that second bash script. After that, move on to the next step in the main script. I've put this together after spending hours searching on the internet. I know that its far from correct, but I'm stuck.

```
#!/bin/bash

<<EOF

\c database;

COPY (
select 'cp ./branding/'||value||' ./customization/'||replace(value,'curric-mobile:','') from branding_resource
where media_type like 'image%'
and name like 'curric-mobile%'
and account_uid = 'b1b08a9e-9310-41ce-b2cb-6b4d590c8104')
TO '/tmp/t1.sh';
EOF

if [[ -f /tmp/t1.sh ]]

chmod +x /tmp/t1.sh

/tmp/t1.sh | tee -a /tmp/t1.log
```

The output of the script should look like:

```
cp ./branding/curric-mobile:c9bec2f6-0b13-4243-8176-d0dc27774fd9.png ./customization/c9bec2f6-0b13-4243-8176-d0dc27774fd9.png
cp ./branding/curric-mobile:6f3d3554-03bc-4771-9069-60c82ebc64c5.jpg ./customization/6f3d3554-03bc-4771-9069-60c82ebc64c5.jpg
cp ./branding/curric-mobile:f32aae31-5ef6-4a1c-893f-8d7bbd560707.png ./customization/f32aae31-5ef6-4a1c-893f-8d7bbd560707.png
cp ./branding/curric-mobile:4a1c88a8-60c0-4878-9de2-fa141fec3391.png ./customization/4a1c88a8-60c0-4878-9de2-fa141fec3391.png
...
```

Thanks!

Comment: `cat > /tmp` is incorrect, you don't want to be writing to the directory. Does `/tmp/t1.sh` exist before this script runs? Does `copy ... to ...` append or overwrite? You need to use a full or relative path to scripts not in the `$PATH` so `/tmp/t1.sh` at the end.

Comment: @EtanReisner I have been looking at a lot of other scripts that include cat, but I couldn't find an explanation of what it does. I can remove that. t1.sh does not exist before the script runs. The goal would be to create it.

Comment: I didn't say remove the line. I said that specific formulation is wrong. `cat` reads its input files and con**cat**enates them together to its output (pass-through filter). Does `copy ... to ...` create its target file? Because if it does then you don't need the file to exist beforehand. Is the output of that db query the script you need to run or data to run the script with?

Comment: @EtanReisner `    copy ... to ...` should create the target file. I'm not sure if that's the correct postgres syntax. The output would be the script to run. An example is added.

Comment: You need to send that heredoc (`<<EOF` to `EOF` contents) to postgres to run it but if that creates the file that should be all you need to do there then just chmod and execute the resulting script.

Comment: Can you test @Etan suggestions: `cat > /tmp/t1.sh << EOF`. Do you need the tmp table or can you just redirect the output of the sql into a new scriptfile? Or is there a way to llok to the actual files that need to be renamed without sql (find with date, all files in `branding/curric-mobile`) ?

Comment: I don't know postgres but if it can take a script as an argument then just `psql "\c database ........"` might be enough to get the `t1.sh` script written correctly.

Comment: @WalterA I've updated the code with what I believe to be the correct syntax. I haven't tested this yet, I should be able to this afternoon. Let me know if you see any issue with the above.

Comment: This is really, really unsafe. PostgreSQL doesn't know how to generate safely shell-quoted strings. Emit your content in an unambiguously-parsed form (NUL-delimited, ideally) and you're in a better place to generate commands elsewhere.

Comment: To say the above a bit differently: Dumping database content into a buffer which is going to be run through a shell parser is just as awful as dumping variables into a buffer which is going to be parsed as SQL syntax, and opens up you to a parallel of the same kinds of attacks. Keep code and data separate from each other.

Answer (score 0):

This is still broken, because it needs to have the query amended to exclude values which contain `\x01` or `\x02` characters, but it's a little closer to something reasonable:

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS=$'\x02' read -r -d $'\x01' -a fields; do
  cp -- "./branding/${fields[0]}" "./customization/${fields[0]#curric-mobile:}"
done < <(psql -q -t -R $'\x01' -F $'\x02' --pset='format=unaligned' <<'EOF'
  SELECT value
  FROM branding_resource
  WHERE media_type like 'image%'
    AND name like 'curric-mobile%'
    AND account_uid = 'b1b08a9e-9310-41ce-b2cb-6b4d590c8104'
EOF
)
```

If you don't set `PGDATABASE`, `PGUSER`, and other relevant environment variables, add command-line arguments with the appropriate data as necessary.

---

Note that we aren't trying to generate shell scripts from inside the database at all, but merely pulling out data (in a well-defined format), and running commands based on that data.

This prevents shell injection attacks, which the other approach was badly prone to. Even if a `value` column in `branding_resource` contains something like `$(rm -rf /)`, there's no risk of that code being executed as given here.